# Zend Framework 2 Current Resource Name

Tags: zend-framework2

I am currently building my own ACL, and I want to know how to get the name of the current resource.

Comment: Ressources are no magic, you define them yourself. It depends on you how you name those ressources. Ressources can be names, they can be matched against controllernames, against routenames, etc... Maybe check out BjyAuthorize to see how others have done it, it's a great Module https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize

Answer (score 2):

You are responsible for setting the resource ID/Name of resrouces in your system.

One way to do this is to implement the **ResourceInterface**.

this only has one method, getResourceId() which will return a unique identifier for the resource in question.

A simple example would be to have a controller, which will create it's resource name/id based on the controller/action name. Obviously this is a simple example which could have clashes between modules, but it's a simple example.

```
class AclController extends AbstractActionController implements ResourceInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns the string identifier of the Resource.
     * By default we'll just use controller/action
     * 
     * e.g. mvc:index/index
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getResourceId()
    {
        //$request = $this->getRequest();
        /* @var $request \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request */
        $routeMatch = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch();
        /* @var $routeMatch \Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\RouteMatch */
        $controller = $routeMatch->getParam('controller', 'noaccess');
        $action = $routeMatch->getParam('action', 'noaccess');

        return 'mcv:' . $controller . '/' . $action;
    }
}
```

You can then use any object which implements the ResourceInterface directly with the ACL

```
// resource can be any object implementing the interface
$acl->addResource($resource);
```

Answer (score 0):

[As Andrew has already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15474188/347063), the one responsible of building [ACL resource identifiers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.permissions.acl.intro.html#resources) is you. The MVC layer itself has no concept of "Acl Resource IDs".

As @Sam said, you may want to peek into how BjyAuthorize does it.

The nearest concept to a "resource ID" in zend framework 2 are:

- The route names
- The controller names (as defined in the controller manager service locator)

These are both things defined in your configuration, and can be read from the configuration as well.

[BjyAuthorize](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize/) does not read the resource names automatically, but it abstracts them anyway (when access is requested) in a so-called "[controller guard](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize/blob/1.2.3/src/BjyAuthorize/Guard/Controller.php)" and in a "[route guard](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize/blob/1.2.3/src/BjyAuthorize/Guard/Route.php)", which are "firewalls" that protect your application from unwanted access.

In the controller guard, each controller resource ID looks like one of the following:

```
controller/%controller_name%:%action_name
controller/%controller_name%:%http_method
controller/%controller_name%
```

While routes have the following syntax:

```
route/%route_name%
```

BjyAuthorize only silently fails on missing resources (by catching [`Zend\Permissions\Acl\Exception\InvalidArgumentException`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.1.3/library/Zend/Permissions/Acl/Exception/InvalidArgumentException.php), but when a resource exists, it has been manually entered by configuration, as Andrew said.